# ReactJS How to use withRouter inside app.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to use withRouter so I could use history in order to redirect user when JWT expires and he is logouted automatically

I tried to import withRouter like I use it in other components and wrap the `export default App` with `withRouter` like this: `export default withRouter(App);`

But this is the error im getting :

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use Route outside a Router
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';
import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from './actions/authActions';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import UsersManagement from './components/UsersManagement';
import Login from './components/Login';
import AddUser from './components/users/AddUser';

import './App.css';

if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser(this.props.history));
    window.location.href = '/login';
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="container">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Navbar} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={UsersManagement} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/add-user" component={AddUser} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that you can *only* use `withRouter` for components that **are children of `<Router />`** and since App isn't (it's a container component of `<Router />`) it throws an error.

Also, this logic should be inside some component that gets required props:

```
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser(this.props.history));
    window.location.href = '/login';
  }
}
```

Comment: this check is required is jwtToken is expired after 1 hour, where else can i put this logic to check this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Router` in index.js and mount App for all routes

```js
// In index.js
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
</Provider>

// In App.js

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
      const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
      store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
      const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
      if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
        store.dispatch(logoutUser(this.props.history));
        window.location.href = '/login';
      }
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
        <>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Navbar} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={UsersManagement} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/add-user" component={AddUser} />
        </>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: what happens if your App is a Functional component and not a Class component; you cannot then use this.props ?

Comment: then you will use just `props`

Comment: ok, I have to write as `function App(props) {}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using axios for requests, you cold use interceptors to verify the responses and then logout/redirect the user.

```
// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```